# JasmineJS 'isNot' property

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Real quick about `jasmine.addMatchers`. With the latest Jasmine build from git, it appears as though the format for doing custom matchers is vastly different than code I'm seeing in the 'Jasmine JavaScript Testing' book. In the book it has code such as:

```
this.actual or maybe even this.isNot
```

The new format is something like:

```
compare: function (actual, expected) {
    return {
        pass: some true or false statement...
    }
}
```

So, in this case, the 'this.actual' is actually the passed in argument 'actual', which is cool. How about accessing the isNot property if we're calling a new matcher such as:

```
expect(investment).not.toBeAGoodInvestment();
```

So, inside the body of 'toBeAGoodInvestment', we should be able to access the 'isNot' property. Not sure how to do that with the new format. I figured out how to set the this.message from the old way to the new way as in:

```
return {
    pass: some statement...,
    message: 'some message'
}
```

The message we would want to have show up in the jasmine reporter would be dynamic based on whatever the 'isNot' is set to.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around in the actual Jasmine.js source, I found out where the arguments were getting passed into custom matcher's compare function, and indeed, the 'isNot' was not making it's way in at all. The 'this.isNot' was available in the context of the 'Expectation.prototype.wrapCompare' function within the Jasmine source itself but where it was really needed was the custom matcher I created.

So now in this wrapCompare function, I simply added the args.push statement within the 'if' statement as in:

```
if (this.isNot) {
    //-- Added this line
    args.push(this.isNot);
    matcherCompare = matcher.negativeCompare || defaultNegativeCompare;
}
```

Now, calling the matcher, I can do this:

```
expect(investment).not.toBeAGoodInvestment();
```

And then the actual matcher it will look something like this:

```
toBeAGoodInvestment: function () {
    return {
        compare: function (actual, isNot) {
            return {
                pass: actual.isGood(),
                message: 'Expected investment to be a ' + 
                   ((isNot) ? 'bad' :  'good') + ' investment'
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Nice little research task here to figure out what Jasmine was doing behind the scenes.

Any other way to get the 'isNot' injected into the compare function, let me know.